# FusionCharts Uncaught Error, Data must be provided in 2D array format or array of json objects

Tags: javascript, laravel

For a project i'm working on with Fusioncharts to render a TimeSeries Chart. The data for the chart is provided by Laravel by passing it through a controller.

Now after a couple of days of debugging, frustration and not being able to figure out the issue i'm here.
I've created a timeseries chart and am trying to render this chart in a div i defined in my blade directive.

I followed [this](https://www.fusioncharts.com/fusiontime/examples/join-missing-data?framework=javascript) tutorial and read the docs about the specific graph but i end up with the following error:

```
fusioncharts.js:19 Uncaught Error: Data must be provided in 2D array format or array of json objects
```

The error itself is pretty clear, the data provided doesnt match the rules that fusioncharts have for delivering the data to the chart. So i started looking at my code and started looking the way i build up my json. The entire proces in creating the json is pretty straight forward and this is the output:

```
[{"timestamp":"2020-09-25 11:21:24","value":"268.00"},{"timestamp":"2020-09-25 11:21:24","value":"268.00"},{"timestamp":"2020-09-25 11:21:24","value":"268.00"},{"timestamp":"2020-09-25 11:21:25","value":"268.00"},{"timestamp":"2020-09-25 11:21:25","value":"268.00"},{"timestamp":"2020-09-25 11:21:25","value":"268.00"},{"timestamp":"2020-09-25 11:21:25","value":"268.00"},{"timestamp":"2020-09-25 11:21:25","value":"268.00"},{"timestamp":"2020-09-25 11:21:25","value":"268.00"},{"timestamp":"2020-09-25 11:21:25","value":"268.00"},{"timestamp":"2020-09-25 11:21:25","value":"268.00"},{"timestamp":"2020-09-25 11:21:25","value":"268.00"},{"timestamp":"2020-09-25 11:21:25","value":"268.00"}]
```

In the example fusioncharts provided they use [this](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/fusion.store/ft/data/join-missing-data-data.json) link to get the data. After looking at both data objects i could find a big difference apart from the key in mine.

This is the code i use to create a chart.

```
 Promise.all([
            @json($machine->coldData),
            @json($machine->coldDataSchema),
        ]).then(function(res) {
            const data = res[0];
            const schema = res[1];

            const dataStore = new FusionCharts.DataStore().createDataTable(data, schema);

            new FusionCharts({
                type: "timeseries",
                renderAt: "graph-container",
                width: "100%",
                height: "400",
                dataSource: {
                    data: dataStore,
                    chart:{
                        "theme": "fusion"
                    },
                    caption: {
                        text: "Products on pallet."
                    },
                    subcaption: {
                        text: "Lorem Ipsum...."
                    },
                    yaxis: [
                        {
                            plot: [
                                {
                                    value: "Products",
                                    connectnulldata: true
                                }
                            ],
                            title: "Products on pallet",
                            min: "130"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }).render();
        });
```

Its almost the same as the code in the tutorial but i get the error. I also tried the links in the tutorial but get the same error.
Can someone explain why this error occurs and how i should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly provide the schema in the given format below :

```
[{
    "name": "Time",
    "type": "date",
    "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
}, {
    "name": "Products",
    "type": "number"
}]
```

As per the data you have provided, it seems that the data is given in array of objects format and not in 2d array. In order to make your sample work please provide the data in the 2d array format. Below is an example of the same.

```
[
    [
      "2020-09-25 11:21:24",
      268
    ],
    [
      "2020-09-25 11:21:24",
      230
    ],
]
```